# use WordNet to generalize specific word to higher-order concept

Tags: machine-learning, prolog, nlp, wordnet

Does [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) have "higher order" concepts? How to generate them for a given word?

I have a corpus of data in the form of prolog 'facts'. I want to generalize the conceptual components, i.e. `'contains'('oranges', 'vitamin c').` and `'contains'('spinach','iron').` would be generalized to `'contains'(<food>, <nutrient>).`

I don't know WordNet very well, so one thing I was thinking about was just to generate all possible hypernyms and then combinatorially elaborate every possible new rule, but this is sort of a 'brute force' approach.

Does WordNet store higher order concepts such as <food> for instance? That might make it easier, because then I can just create one new rule with the higher order concept of that particular variable, assuming that there is one in WordNet, as opposed to perhaps fifty or one hundred if I do it the brute force way.

So what I actually want to know is: is there a command to generate the higher order concepts for each of the three components within a given 'fact'? Or maybe just for the two that are inside the parentheses. If such a command exits, what is it?

Below is some of the data I'm working with for reference.

```
'be'('mr jiang', 'representing china').
'be'('hrh', 'britain').
'be more than'('# distinguished guests', 'the principal representatives').
'end with'('the playing of the british national anthem', 'hong kong').
'follow at'('the stroke of midnight', 'this').
'take part in'('the ceremony', 'both countries').
'start at about'('# pm', 'the ceremony').
'end about'('# am', 'the ceremony').
'lower'('the british hong kong flag', '# royal hong kong police officers').
'raise'('the sar flag', 'another #').
'leave for'('the royal yacht britannia', 'the #').
'hold by'('the chinese and british governments', 'the handover of hong kong').
'rise over'('this land', 'the regional flag of the hong kong special administrative region of the people \'s republic of china').
'cast eye on'('hong kong', 'the world').
'hold on'('schedule', 'the # governments').
'be festival for'('the chinese nation', 'this').
'go in'('the annals of history', 'july # , #').
'become master of'('this chinese land', 'the hong kong compatriots').
'enter era of'('development', 'hong kong').
'remember'('mr deng xiaoping', 'history').
'be along'('the course', 'it').
'resolve'('the hong kong question', 'we').
'wish to express thanks to'('all the personages', 'i').
'contribute to'('the settlement of the hong kong', 'both china and britain').
'support'('hong kong \'s return', 'the world').
```

Comment: I don't think you will find a ready to use 'command'. Also, beware that Wordnet 3.0 has a bug (a cyclic hyp)

Comment: maybe map the words from wordnet to an existing ontology such as http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/fo

Comment: @CapelliC do you think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102112/prolog-function-to-learn-correlative-inference-from-facts) makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Wordnet refers to higher-order concepts as "hypernyms". A hypernym for the color "green," for instance, is "chromatic color", because the color green belongs to the higher-order class of chromatic colors.

One should note that Wordnet differentiates between "words" (strings of characters) and "sysnets" (the meaning we associate with a given string of characters). Just as one word can have multiple meanings, one string can have multiple synsets. If you want to retrieve all of the higher-order meanings for a given word, you can run these lines in Python:

```
from nltk import wordnet as wn

# If you are using nltk version 3.0.1, the following will tell you all the synsets for "green" and will thenn find all of their hypernyms. If you're running nltk 3.0.0, you can change the first line to `for synset in wn.synsets('bank'):
for synset in wn.wordnet.synsets('green'):
    for hypernym in synset.hypernyms():
        print synset, hypernym
```