# prolog function to infer new facts from data

Tags: function, machine-learning, prolog, logic, nlp

I have a dataset containing "facts" recognizable to prolog, i.e.:

```
'be'('mr jiang', 'representative of china').
'support'('the establishment of the sar', 'mr jiang').
'be more than'('# distinguished guests', 'the principal representatives').
'end with'('the playing of the british national anthem', 'hong kong').
'follow at'('the stroke of midnight', 'this').
'take part in'('the ceremony', 'both countries').
'start at about'('# pm', 'the ceremony').
'end about'('# am', 'the ceremony').
```

I want the system to recognize that 'mr jiang' is referenced in both of the following "facts":

```
'be'('mr jiang', 'representative of china').
'support'('the establishment of the sar', 'mr jiang').
```

Subsequently the system should then infer:

```
'support'('the establishment of the sar', 'representative of china').
```

I've spent some time looking at the FOIL algorithm, do you think that would do the trick? But I guess that's overkill.

Would something like this work:

```
'X'('Y', 'Z') :-
     'A'('Y', 'B') ∧ '0'('B', 'Z');
```

Is it possible to make such a general "rule" like that? Or does it have to be more specific?

Comment: I think your best bet is to represent your data with facts with the same functor, `arg1_rel_arg2/3`, as in `arg1_rel_arg2(Arg1, Rel, Arg2)`, instead of different `Rel(Arg1, Arg2)` where each `Rel` is a different fact name. This will make it easier to work with it.

Comment: Is your interest specific to the facts `'be'/2` and `'support'/2`? Or are you interested in transitive relationships between any two different facts? Based upon semantics, it would seem some restrictions would apply. Also, you probably want to use a different functor other than `'support'` for the inferred information to avoid overloading `'support'/2` with two different meanings.